# Why's the HTTP address on my app blocked by Transport Security?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, https, app-transport-security

I'm working on an iOS, Objective-C application. 
How do I address the following error? A simple step-by-step guide would be much appreciated.

"App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file".

Answer (score 0):

I have solved as plist file.

add this two line in your Info.plist file

1. Add a NSAppTransportSecurity : Dictionary.
2. named " NSAllowsArbitraryLoads " as Boolean : YES

   [image]Add Subkey

Comment: Thanks so much, that's very helpful. :)  P.S I would up your score, but for some reason I don't yet have authorisation.

Comment: @C-Smith accept as a answer.

Comment: @C-Smith take a tour. http://stackoverflow.com/tour